# How to disable gyro based rotation on mobile phones

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr

i want to disable the camera rotation, while being on mobile.

I though making look-controls="hmdEnabled:false" would disable moving the camera along with the mobile device, yet it didn't work.

I tried to find which controls should i disable, but i only found some intel stating, that WebVr drivers rotate the scene @HMD orientation, not directly from the gyroscopes.

Nonetheless, I have no idea how to lock the camera, so it can be only moved by dragging Your finger.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your own control scheme, you'll need to make your own controls.  You can copy and paste some code from the look-controls and customize it: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/look-controls.js

Comment: yea, i guess i can try to override the isMobile. Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 3):

I packaged up a component that does this at https://github.com/AVGP/a-touch-controls:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-entity camera touch-controls></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

These controls are using mouse (click and drag) or finger (swipe) movements to move around the camera, but does not use the gyroscope on mobile, except when explicitely entering VR mode, which still permits Cardboard usage etc.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: fair point, nonetheless: This is precisely what the OP was looking for, without the "code it yourself" issue. I have since elaborated a little on it. LMK if that's fine.